# How to run Jupyter notebook in an external server via SSH without any connection timed out issues?

Tags: ssh, jupyter

I’m working on a machine learning project on an external linux server owned by my university. I can access the server via SSH and using PuTTy and the command

```
Jupyter notebook —-no-browser —port
```

to send the Jupyter notebook GUI interface back to my personal computer.

The problem is I ran into connection timed out/ PuTTy Software caused connection abort error often. The internal network of my university isn’t that good and I suspect that this might be a cause of the connection timed out thing.

Are there any way to run an .ipynb file in the server without sending any data back to my personal computer, then I can come back in the server and collect the result?

Comment: Try to run your command in a `screen` or `tmux` session. So it can keep running even when the connection gets disconnected,